# Asp .NET MVC Hide Row and update DB values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a database (SQL Server) with clients and a MVC plataform, and i want a row to be "hidden" on the web platform with validation at a specific value in the "status" column (True / false) in the database.
Exemple: if the status value is True, the row appears, if it is false, it hides the row.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save some traffic on your website In the controller before returning the View(model) line filter the model by the status and if you need the data to be available in client then just make a custom html table in the view file and populate it with razor syntax while not adding the rows which their status is false